# Proof of arithmetical identities $-(-m)=m$ and $-0=0$

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic

I have two prepositions to prove with the basic axioms for addition and multiplication:

1. For all $m \in\mathbb Z$, $-(-m) = m$

\begin{align*}
(-m) + -(-m) &= 0\\
(-m) + m &= 0 \\
(-m) + -(-m) &= (-m) + m \\
m + (-m) + -(-m) &= m + (-m) + m\\
0 + -(-m) &= 0 + m \\
-(-m) &= m
\end{align*}

2. $-0 = 0$

\begin{align*}
(-0) + -(-0) &= 0\\
(-0) + 0 &= 0\\
(-0) = 0\\
\end{align*}

The second step is based on the first preposition.

I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Comment: You did well! It's totally correct.

Comment: @Spark Alright! :D thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your proofs are sufficiently correct.